# Pool comparison list?

Tags: mining-pools

Where can I find a list of pools and their features? I want to choose the best pool. On google I find no good comparison.

Comment: What's wrong with https://litecoin.info/Mining_pool_comparison?

Answer (score 4):

https://blockchain.info/pools

---

You can browse bitcoin wiki:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_mining_pools

---

As Egor notice, here a litecoin.info:

http://litecoin.info/Mining_Pool_Comparison

---

Partially outdated, http://pastehtml.com/view/awb1vg03r.html

---

Also, there is thousand of sites, like this:

- http://www.coinindex.org
- http://howtobitcoin.info
- http://www.tblob.org
- etc...

Probably, nowhere you can find a full list of alt-coins pools, because this part of net changes ***so fast***.

See,

- https://www.google.com/search?q=BOTPOOL
- https://www.google.com/search?q=MPOS+by+TheSerapher <-- from the second page start pools, 6 pages, about 20 pools.

Answer (score 1):

I really like this blog: http://organofcorti.blogspot.com/
A weekly report is posted and the guy puts a lot of interesting info about pools.

give a look.

Answer (score -1):

On [BitcoinChain.com](https://bitcoinchain.com/pools) you can find a comparison of mining pools. They list pools with the number of blocks found, whether you can Solo and Cloud mine with them, and what payout method they use.